# Find sample size of $S$ for a uniform probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The CDF of $X$ is $F(t) = P[X \le t]$. Also, the empirical CDF with a set of i.i.d. samples is $F_s(t) = \dfrac{1}{|S|}\sum_{i=1}^{s} 1(X_i \le t)$

---

What is the sample size of $S$ be to to have

$P_s [|F(t) - F_s (t)| < \alpha] \ge 1 - \beta$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I suspect your question needs some tidying, with a summation in the empirical CDF and $X \notin S$ rather than $X \ni S$.  The phase "sample size" might also help understanding. Your edit to the title obscures the point that if $X$ has a continuous CDF you may as well assume without loss of generality that $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and that simplifies $F(x)$

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes you suggested. I have tried Hoeffding, but it appears to be the wrong instance to use it. I'll try using the DKW inequality instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is the [DKW inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality). Let $F_n(x)$ be the empirical distribution function formed from $n$ iid samples of a random variable with CDF $F(x)$:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\;\;P\left(\sup_{x \in \Bbb R} \left| F_n(x)-F(x)\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$

This implies:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\;\;P\left(\sup_{x \in \Bbb R} \left| F_n(x)-F(x)\right|\leq \epsilon\right)>1- 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$

So $\beta = 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$

Comment: Thank you! Using Hoeffding was a blunder on my part. I can see how DKW is useful here.